# Foundation off canvas menu always visible on mobile

Tags: zurb-foundation, off-canvas-menu

Currently [on this site](http://mpw.kiwicreative.net) the off canvas menu is always visible for mobile and small desktop screens... Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The site is built using the Joints WP theme based upon the Zurb Foundation framework.

Thanks in advance, 
Adam

Comment: it is not clear what you're asking...

Comment: Hi elicohenator, thanks for your comment. My question is how can I make the off canvas navigation stay off canvas on mobile and appear when the menu link is clicked, currently it is visible without having to click the menu link. I hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

That suggests you have a jQuery problem and Foundation uses jQuery to hide the (not relevant) portion of the navigation on small / large screens.

I'm going to guess that if you change this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var temp = "";
    $(':input').click(function() {
        temp = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        $(this).attr('placeholder','');
        $(this).blur(function() {
            $(this).attr('placeholder',temp);
        });
    });
});
```

To this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var temp = "";
    jQuery(':input').click(function() {
        temp = jQuery(this).attr('placeholder');
        jQuery(this).attr('placeholder','');
        jQuery(this).blur(function() {
            jQuery(this).attr('placeholder',temp);
        });
    });
});
```

In `script.js`

Things may work (though I have not checked the voracity of the code).

Have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/ for more information on how jQuery can run into conflicts.